# Writing combined conditions to work with click in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I can't figure out how to write the correctly the conditionals to allow click to be invoked in knockout.js. I managed to create 4 buttons that when I click on them an observable array is being populated with their values. I want to prevent the same value being passed in this array and I also want to prevent more than 2 values being passed. My starting code is:

```
<table>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="1" data-bind="click: hasBeenAdded() || isFull() ? null : function() { addNumber(1); }">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="2" data-bind="click: hasBeenAdded() || isFull() ? null :function() { addNumber(2); }">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="3" data-bind="click: hasBeenAdded() || isFull() ? null : function() { addNumber(3); }">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="4" data-bind="click: hasBeenAdded() || isFull() ? null : function() { addNumber(4); }">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<h3>Available columns created by the user</h3>
Column: <strong data-bind="text: column"></strong>
```

And my view model is:

```
function viewModel() {
        var self = this;

        self.hasBeenAdded = ko.observable(false); 
        self.isFull = ko.observable(false);

        self.column = ko.observableArray();

        self.addNumber = function(data) {
            //console.log('Added ', data);

            self.hasBeenAdded = true;
            self.column.push(data);
        }

        if (self.column().length > 3) {
            self.isFull = ko.observable(true);
        }

    }
```

Can you help me properly write the hasBeenAdded and isFull booleans to work with the click data-bind?

Comment: Consider moving the conditions into the `addNumber()` method.

Comment: In think you need to set up a couple of computed values http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knockout is a MVVM-style library. Get in the habit of writing all of your logic in view models, and have the view just reflect the state of those view models. For one, have a look at how [`computed` observables work](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html).

In practice, this means all the logic you're placing in your view should be inside the click handler. In addition, it seems you want:

- If the click handler *is* called with an inappropriate value, nothing happens;
- That the button is disabled in certain circumstances.

Here's an example of how to do that:

```js
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  
  self.column = ko.observableArray([]);

  self.hasBeenAdded = function(data) {
    return self.column.indexOf(data) >= 0;
  }
  
  self.isFull = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.column().length > 1;
  });
  
  self.canAdd = function(data) {
    return !self.isFull() && !self.hasBeenAdded(data);
  }


  self.addNumber = function(data) {
    if (self.canAdd(data)) {
      self.column.push(data);
    }
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```css
input[type="button"] { background-color: white; }
input[type="button"]:disabled { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="1" data-bind="click: function() { addNumber(1); }, enable: canAdd(1)">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="2" data-bind="click: function() { addNumber(2); }, enable: canAdd(2)">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="3" data-bind="click: function() { addNumber(3); }, enable: canAdd(3)">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="4" data-bind="click: function() { addNumber(4); }, enable: canAdd(4)">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

Column: <strong data-bind="text: column"></strong>
```

You have a few other problems too though, most notably that your code isn't very DRY. But given the code you've posted in the question related to [my earlier suggestion to DRY that out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34406512/419956) I think you have a reason not to change that?

Comment: Thank you. I really liked the way you wrote the hasBeenAdded function. Could I use it in data-bind to change the style of the button that I just added? I try to do this but not working `<td>
                                <input type="button" data-bind="value: $data, click: $parent.addNumber, style: {background: hasBeenAdded() ? red : 'white' }"> </td>` Shouldn't it return true and change the style?

Comment: Ya sure. Just watch your quotes, and mind that buttons are not the easiest element to style well cross-browser. In addition, it may be easier to use proper CSS to style `:disabled` buttons? I've updated my sample for the latter.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to have an array of values for buttons, rather than explicitly creating each. That way, you can use `foreach`, and the `click` binding will get the value as its data parameter.

`hasBeenAdded` should be a dictionary that starts out empty and you check whether the clicked item is in it inside `addNumber`.

To properly print out your columns, you need either a `foreach` or to turn the array into a string using `join`.

```js
function viewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.hasBeenAdded = ko.observable({});
  self.numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  self.isFull = ko.observable(false);

  self.column = ko.observableArray();

  self.addNumber = function(data) {
    if (!self.hasBeenAdded[data]) {
      self.hasBeenAdded[data] = true;
      self.column.push(data);
    }
  };

  if (self.column().length > 3) {
    self.isFull = ko.observable(true);
  }

}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table>

  <tr data-bind="foreach:numbers">
    <td>
      <input type="button" data-bind="value: $data, click: $parent.addNumber">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<h3>Available columns created by the user</h3>
Column: <strong data-bind="text: column().join(',')"></strong>
```